# Get bitmap width and height is varing in same bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

In my application, I need to find out exact dimensions of a bitmap in pixels. The real dimension of the bitmap is 600x583. When I call

**mBitmap.getWidth();
mBitmap.getHeight();**

I get 300x292 as the dimensions of the bitmap.

After I again call that same bitmap with 
**mBitmap.getWidth();
mBitmap.getHeight();**

Then I get 240x233. Everytime the ratio is same. But it's not the correct value. How can I overcome this issue?

```
mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.birdsketchfinal2).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        height=mBitmap.getHeight();
        width=mBitmap.getWidth();

        //In here I get 300X292

        disWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        disHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        modified=((float)disWidth/(float)width)*height;

        mBitmap= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, disWidth, (int)modified, true);

        height=mBitmap.getHeight();
        width=mBitmap.getWidth();

                    //I here I get 240x233
```

Comment: Post the code where bitmap is stored and queried.

Comment: put birdsketchfinal2.png in drawable-nodpi folder

Comment: There is not a folder called drawable-nodpi